# Matrix of bar charts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I came across a post (https://peltiertech.com/stacked-bar-chart-alternatives/). I would like to draw a chart similar to last on mentioned in the post. The image of the chart is attached.
Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a tabular with color lines, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\myrule}[2]{\color{#1}\rule{#2}{2mm}}
\newcommand{\tbl}[1]{\myrule{blue!80!black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\qlik}[1]{\myrule{red!80!black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\orac}[1]{\myrule{orange}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tib}[1]{\myrule{pink}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rllll}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{How BI Customers Use Their Platforms}}\\
& Tableau & Qliktech & Oracle & Tibco\\
Using parameterized reports & \tbl{2cm} & \qlik{2cm} & \orac{3cm} & \tib{1.5cm} \\
viewing static management reports & \tbl{1.5cm} & \qlik{1.2cm} & \orac{1.1cm} & \tib{1cm} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Ignasi, Can I display the value in the cell? For instance, a cell having \qlik{2cm} displays 2 also in the middle of the colored line.

Comment: @Jitendra I know how to write it after the line, but not in the middle. If all values are in `cm`, use `\newcommand{\myrule}[2]{\color{#1}\rule{#2cm}{2mm}}` and change all color commands like this: \newcommand{\tbl}[1]{\myrule{blue!80!black}{#1}\ #1}. With these changes, values inside the tabular will be: `\tbl{2}`.

Comment: @Jitendra If you still want values in the middle, please make a new question. It will have more visibility and I'm sure someone will answer it.

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi. can I read the values (2cm, 3cm) from a csv file?

Comment: Probably, yes, but this is another question. PLease make a new question, if it's possible showing some effort on your part, providing some code and an example of csv file. I'm sure you'll get better answers.

Comment: when I tried to write values after line, it working with \tbl{2cm} but not with \tbl{2}. How can I reduce cm from text?